# Windows Azure - CDN as a Website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, cdn, azure-worker-roles

I'm using Windows Azure for hosting my MVC3 project.
This project is an online store for Facebook pages which divided into two parts:

1. Management panel for sellers which allow to manage products and Orders.
2. Online store for consumers which allow to browse products and place order(s).

My question is if it's possible to place the whole front-end on CDN (the online store that placed on Facebook page). What constitutes usability best practice for this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really possible.  Though, you can place large portions of static content up there.  However, you cannot use the CDN in practice as a full webserver.  Since underlying resources are tied to blob storage and blob storage is case sensitive, you will find that you will get a lot of 404s in practice (e.g. user types default.html and page is actually Default.html in storage).  Also, you would have no dynamic abilities at all (no .aspx, .php, etc.) nor default pages (http://example.com/ actually might map to http://example.com/index.html).

Use it for what it is good for - quickly delivering static content and caching it on the edge, closest to your consumers.  It is not a replacement for a web server.